# Get values from object through class

Tags: c#, class, static, xna

```
public class BlockType
{
     public static BlockType Dirt_Block = new Block("Blah! values here");
}

public  struct Block
{
    public static string Value;

    public Block(string value)
    {
        value = value;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can get the value from DirtBlock? BlockType.Dirt_Block.Value Dosent work, Im not sure if this is possible, if not any ways to get the same result? (Theres more values, but I shortened it for size) Btw, Im accessing BlockType.Dirt.value from anouther class. I only want to get one value out of it though

Comment: @devdigital Ah I see, How to you think I should do this? I want to have tiles that have a type of block, and an x,y, tiles(blockType,x,y) for each position on my grid, and I want BlockType to hold different kinds of blocks (dirt,wood, metal, etc) To sum it up, I want a blockType with values, and an x,y for each grid value, and a class for different types of blocks. Hmm... How? [Edit, he deleted his post, anyone else?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way to achieve it.

I think this approah provides an easier way to load/save tilemaps, and let defining block properties from text if needed.

Strict OOP with virtual methods and intensive inheritance is not a good idea for a game that may need optimizations to run fine.

Of course it can be improved or done in other way. ;)

```
public struct BlockProperty
{
    public Texture2D Texture;
    public string Name;
}

public class BlockProperties
{
    static readonly List<BlockProperty> Blocks;
    public static readonly BlockProperty Dirt;
    public static readonly BlockProperty Grass;
    public static readonly BlockProperty Wall;

    static BlockProperties( )
    {
        ContentManager Content = Game1.Instance.Content;

        Blocks = new List<BlockProperty>( ) 
        { 
            (Dirt = new BlockProperty( ) { Name = "Dirt", Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>( "textures/dirt" ) }),
            (Grass = new BlockProperty( ) { Name = "Grass", Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>( "textures/grass" ) }),
            (Wall = new BlockProperty( ) { Name = "Wall", Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>( "textures/wall" ) }),
        };
    }

    public static BlockProperty ByName( string name )
    {
        return Blocks.FirstOrDefault( b => b.Name == name );
    }
}


public class Block
{
    public BlockProperty BlockType;
    pulic Vector2 Position;

    public Block( BlockProperty block )
    {
        this.BlockType = block;
    }

     public Block( string block )
    {
        this.BlockType = BlockProperties.ByName(block);
    }
}


public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    public static Game1 Instance { get; private set; }

    Block Block;

    public Game1( )
    {
        Instance = this;

        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager( this );
    }

    protected override void LoadContent( )
    {
        Block = new Block("Dirt") { Position = new Vector2(100,100) };
    }
}
```

Comment: Im going to be creating hundreds of blocks (for positions, not types) Any way to set the position without creating a new Block(). Im leaning towards Mr James Idea, but I cant get the virtual thing right

Comment: You can modify your position when you want, block is an instance... the blockproperty field is what defines how is you block... the line at LoadContent shoul be interpreted as "create a new block of type dirt at position (100,100)"

Comment: Got everything set for this method, since the other one seems to be getting low fps when using larger maps. So when I generate my terrain, how should I set the tile? (Im currently doing currently  `tiles[x,y] = new Tile(BlockType.Whatever,x,y,blah)`) , But not sure what to change to work with your answer. Thanks.

Comment: tiles[x,y] = new Block(BlockProperties.WhatEver) { Position = new Vector2(x,y) };

Comment: Thanks, Works! But still getting low fps, It must be something else, although I like your method alot!

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Dirt_Block` is a `BlockType`, not a `Block`. In fact, I wouldn't expect this code to compile, as there is no way of converting a `Block` to a `BlockType`.

I'm not quite sure what you're after, but it sounds like you have a collection of block types that would suit an enumeration:

```
public enum BlockType
{
   Dirt,
   Wood,
   Metal
}
```

and you have a collection of Blocks that each have a block type:

```
public class Block
{
   public BlockType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Here, we are using a public auto property. You should avoid using public fields (no getters or setters).

Now, to create a new `Block`, you can use object initialisation:

```
var block = new Block { Type = BlockType.Metal };
```

Alternatively, you could create a `Block` constructor which takes a `BlockType` parameter.

Comment: Like it too, How can I define properties of the Dirt,Wood, or Metal blocks?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* you mean `Dirt_Block` to be of type `Block` - your Block  `Value` field is static - that means it is associated with the `Block` type, not any particular instance. Make it a public field (or property) and your access will work:

```
public class BlockType
{
     public static Block Dirt_Block = new Block("Blah! values here");
}

public struct Block
{
  public string Value;

  public Block(string value)
  {
    value = value;
  }
}
```

Also if there is no particular reason you are going with a `struct` here, I would suggest making `Block` a class and expose Value as a public property.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt isn't very clear... but I think what you want is something like this... using OOP paradigm on the block classes.

```
public class BlockType
{
    public virtual string Value;

    public static BlockType Dirt = new Block("Blah! values here");
}

public class Block : BlockType
{
    private string value;

    public Block(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public string Value 
    {
        get { return value; }
    }
}
```

Right?

Comment: Virtual is not a valid identifier, alternative?

Comment: @Fuex I have, take a look at my code here: http://pastebin.com/yJfqnhvT getting the error "The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item"

Comment: lol... that is bad done.. block is inheriting from blocktype, so block has the variables and methods owned by blocktype. You are declaring virtual vars in blocktype like this {public virtual int Height;} that is not needed to be virtual, and you are declaring it again in block as private... that's not needed because Height has been inherited from blocktype, so block has that variable yet...

Comment: I got MRJames method working, Just wondering, How can I load a texture from the BlockType class? With that ill be all set!

Comment: My edits weren't accepted, so here is the code that should work: http://pastebin.com/aveSkBLk

Comment: @Fuex I already got it working, I Just cant seem to load a texture from the blocktype class, A way to get a ContentManager in there?

Comment: @Cyral For load Textures don't pass the `Texture2D`, but the string-path and load it from the constructor like here: http://pastebin.com/UD8CVYC0

Comment: @Blau Yeah, you're right, I think that your solution are better than this.

Comment: After further testing, this method is very slow, with more blocks, im getting 2-3 fps

Comment: Hi all. After testing it with VS2010 found that what I wanted to post was something like this: http://chopapp.com/#rstcukkg   No need to virtual the property Value!